# Why don't cloneNode <script> tags execute?

Tags: javascript, dom

Cloned <script> tags do not execute. Why?

Example:

```
<script id="hello">
  console.log("hello execution count ", window.helloCount++);
</script>

<script id="action">
  document.body.appendChild(
    document.getElementById('hello').cloneNode(true));
  console.log('cloned the script');
</script>
```

After execution, there are two hello scripts in the document, but only one has executed.

http://jsbin.com/zuxoro/1/edit?html,console,output

This is part of a larger problem I am working on, so I know it is a dumb thing to do.

Comment: Could have something to do with internal flags? https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#script

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This behavior is required by the [W3C HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html).

Each `<script>` element has a property flag called "*already started*". The specification says:

> Initially, script elements must have this flag unset (script blocks, when created, are not "already started"). **The cloning steps for script elements must set the "already started" flag on the copy if it is set on the element being cloned.**

And then, later:

> If the script element is marked as having "already started", then the user agent must abort these steps at this point. The script is not executed.

The solution is simply not to clone script elements, but to create completely new elements that are populated with the same content.

Comment: I knew about the already started flag. I'd assume that flag would be cleared on clone. Guess not.

Comment: Is it possible to access these flags with javascript?  And what would the flag be set to for a script which was added by setting innerHTML?  The script is in the DOM, but is not executed.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why it doesn't work with `cloneNode`, but you can achieve the same result by copying the `innerHTML` to a new script node.

```js
var clone = document.createElement('script');
clone.innerHTML = document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML;
document.body.appendChild(clone);
console.log('copied the script');
```

```html
<script>
  window.helloCount = 1;
</script>
<script id="hello">
  console.log("hello execution count ", window.helloCount++);
</script>
<div>Copied scripts do execute</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In principle browser does the following when it executes `<script>` on the page:

If script `<script>` was not executed before it does the following:

1. Takes text from the `<script>`;
2. Calls `eval(thatScriptText)`;
3. Marks the `<script>` DOM node as executed;

When you clone the node it gets that internal "executed" flag too, it prevents the script from further executions.

Solution: if you want script to be re-executed do steps #1 and #2. Cloning is not required in this case.