# Detect if script is "already started"

Tags: javascript, dom

A script inserted via setting `innerHTML`, and a few other circumstances like calling `element.cloneNode(true)` will produce scripts that have an internal "already started" flag set to true.

> The first is a flag indicating whether or not the script block has been "already started". Initially, script elements must have this flag unset (script blocks, when created, are not "already started"). The cloning steps for script elements must set the "already started" flag on the copy if it is set on the element being cloned.
>
> Source: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element

If this internal flag is already already set, the script will not load nor execute.

Is there any way to detect this flag is set in the internal state?

Comment: can you show your code for which you want to detect already started or not

Comment: _"Is there any way to detect this state?"_, _"If already set, the script will not load nor execute"_ Does check for `script` loading and executing not answer Question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @guest271314 No suitable answers on SO, while loads can be detected with `script.load` in HTML5, that falls apart when there's no way to tell scripts that will trigger onload from scripts that will not (e.g scripts with `already started` set to true from cloneNode etc. Hackaround to all of this is to monkey-patch `createElement` with an attribute, but its really heavy handed.

Comment: I think there is no way other than to apply a timing attack (which is probably not very reliable nor practical). Also note that script elements can not execute for other reasons than this flag. But you have not explained why you need to detect this?

Comment: @CasperBeyer STill not following what requirement is? Can you create  jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnk http://plnkr.co to demonstrate each case? What is purpose of cloning a `<script>` element with `element.cloneNode(true)`?

Comment: @zcorpan Gist of it is, can't reliably track `script.onload` on active document scripts without knowing if the tag is an actual script or an inert one, tho not using that approach today (it's for tooling, script loader, not production). Moreso, I'm just curious as I've been reading through a lot of the spec details lately.

Comment: @guest271314 Just an edge case that would be neat to detect, not that uncommon to insert scripts with innerHTML. Use cases, how about console.warning(script, 'will not execute, did you mean for it to?') ;)

Comment: @CasperBeyer you might find this one helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28771829/2020893

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to detect this.